# Factory pattern : iBeacon Delegates are not called from implemention file

Tags: ios, delegates, ibeacon, factory-pattern, eddystone

I introduced  “**Factory Pattern**” in my beacon scanning module. I referred http://crosbymichael.com/objective-c-design-patterns-factory.html

In my Factory class,  2 modes of beacons are switched between Interface classes “**PCGoogleBeacon.h**” and “**PCAppleBeacon.h**”.

//Header file of Factory

```
typedef enum beaconMode {
    iBeacon,
    Eddystone
} BeaconMode;

@interface PCBeaconFinder : NSObject

+(id) searchForBeaconMode:(BeaconMode) beaconMode;

@end
```

//Implementation of Factory

```
+(id) searchForBeaconMode:(BeaconMode) beaconMode
{

    switch (beaconMode ) {

        case iBeacon:

            return   [PCAppleBeacon new];

            break;

        case Eddystone:

            return   [PCGoogleBeacon new];

            break;

        default: NSLog(@"UNKOWN BEACON MODE");


    }

}
```

In my Implementation file for interface classes.

```
//Header file

@protocol PCGetBeacon <NSObject>

-(void) scanBeaconsWithUUID:(NSString *) beaconId;

@end
```

//In the implementation file.  — Implementation of Mode 1

```
#import "PCAppleBeacon.h"

@implementation PCAppleBeacon

-(void) scanBeaconsWithUUID:(NSString *) beaconId {


    self.proximityContentManager = [[ProximityContentManager alloc]
                                    initWithBeaconIDs:@[

                                                        [[BeaconID alloc] initWithUUIDString:beaconId major:0 minor:0]
                                                        ]
                                    beaconContentFactory:[EstimoteCloudBeaconDetailsFactory new]];

    self.proximityContentManager.delegate = self;

    [self.proximityContentManager startContentUpdates];


    NSLog(@"----------- > iBeacon  Implementation Called ");


}

//iBeacon Delegates goes here …


@end
```

// In the same above file— Implementation of Mode 2

```
#import "PCGoogleBeacon.h"

@implementation PCGoogleBeacon

-(void) scanBeaconsWithUUID:(NSString *) beaconId {

    _scanner.delegate = self;

    [_scanner startScanning];

    NSLog(@"----------- > EDDYSTONE  Implementation Called ");

}

//EDDYSTONE Delegates goes here …

@end
```

Everything is fine.  Able to switch as from MainController,

```
 id beaconFinderObject =   [PCBeaconFinder searchForBeaconMode:iBeacon];  //or ‘Eddystone’ for Google beacon interface.

 [beaconFinderObject scanBeaconsWithUUID:@"B0702880-A295-A8AB-F734-031A98A512DE"];
```

**But why the delegates of corresponding classes are not called. ?**

*Note: Beacons are in the range.*

Comment: For `[PCGoogleBeacon scanBeaconsWithUUID:]`, it looks like the beaconId is discarded. For `PCAppleBeacon`, it is set up for major/minor of 0/0. Are you sure they're configured to scan for the correct beacon id's?

Comment: @ama111 yes, I assure you that MacBeacon(OSX) app used for broadcast with above UUID, Major and minor. Thanks for the reply

Comment: It works well if i add delegates in MainViewController class after removing the factory design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After creating "Shared Instance" for both `PCAppleBeacon` and `PCGoogleBeacon` class solved my problem.** :-)

*Explanation* :
Delegate methods of above classes are not called because 2 times those instantiated. First time instantiated in 'Implementation of Factory Class' along with setting it's delegates. Second time from the class Main view controller, where it's protocols are not implemented, hence receiver fails.